# ViewPager not occupying full size(width) in Samsung Galaxy s4

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I had used Universal Image Downloader for displaying the list of images through ViewPager using the below code.

```
ViewPager layout

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        **<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dot_images_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />**
    </RelativeLayout>

I am displaying the list of images using a class which extends PagerAdapter.

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private String[] images;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
            this.images = images;
            inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View container) {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);


            imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {


                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }



    }

**item_pager_image layout** 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="1dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is working fine in all the devices except in Samsung Galaxy S4.Image is not occupying the total width of the device though i had mentioned android:layout_width="fill_parent" in the code. Can any one help me.

Scree shot below

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just assume that the image is simply not as big (wide) as the screen and thus doesn't fill it out. To verify that you can give a background color to the imageview and see whether the imageview itself fills its parent (the borders beside the image are in that color).

In that case look at [ImageView's ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). I think fitXY should work for you.

You can add a scaleType via [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29) in java or with the xml attribute [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType)